# Looping Through Sheets in a Workbook for a Specific Cell to be Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked on this site and many others but not finding the exact piece of code in Excel VBA that I am looking for. Probably not asking in the correct way. I have a workbook that has a worksheet for each day of the year each label like "mmddyy". What I am attempting to find is a piece of code that will loop through each worksheet specifically looking at Cell location D1 until it finds the first Worksheet where that cell is blank. then run the remainder of the code which would consist of several copy/paste commands ending with pasting a date in the cell D1 so when the script is ran the next day it now passes over the sheet that was just pasted to.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub FindBlank()

Dim ws as worksheet

For Each ws in ThisworkBook.Worksheets
    If ws.Range("D1") = "" Then
        ws.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

will leave the first worksheet with d1 blank as the active sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub SearchSheet()

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Output As String

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        Output = Sheet.Cells(1, 4) ' Cell D1

        If Output = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Sheet: " & Sheet.Name
            Sheet.Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    ' Clean
    Set Sheet = Nothing

End Sub
```